# Why OS(s) take so much memory. Are they fully optimised?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, memory, performance

Mac Os eating more than 3.5 GB's of Ram:

[image]

I have seen windows and mac os taking about 3-4 GB of ram space even in cleaned PC with no apps opened.
Can't developers further optimise operating systems to eat less ram somewhat like other operating systems (like Lubuntu or many other linux distos) does?

Comment: Noticing in your screenshot that you have a lot of Chrome processes.  So you probably have a lot of Chrome tabs open.  Maybe this is consuming your RAM.  This is not the OSs fault.  Modern websites are often optimized for developer speed/"time-to-market" over anything else, including memory and network footprint.

Comment: Most of your used memory is being allocated to Chrome.

Comment: @LawrenceC Actually just a single tab was opened (stack exchange) while posting the query. I wanted get as minimalistic ram usage due to apps.

Comment: A quick search tells me "Chrome helper processes" are due to plug-ins.  Do you have too many of those?

Answer (score 2):

Unused RAM is wasted RAM. OSes will often use as much RAM as possible for caching in order to speed things up, and they will release the RAM if you need it for running programs. There is no point in having the RAM and then not using it.

Answer (score 1):

The OS is only using 1.11GB RAM [wired memory]. The rest is app memory. Chrome is a known memory hog, so try Safari instead, but that all looks pretty normal to me. Nothing at all to even bother about until that green bar on the left goes orange or red. It's barely used any swap either, which is quite surprising on an 8GB Mac.

BTW, learn & take to heart the modern adage "Empty memory is wasted memory." You want the OS to be as fast as possible. It does this by keeping things in RAM it thinks you may need again. This is a thousand times faster than fetching it from disk, even with modern solid state technology. If this cached RAM space is needed by another process, it will just drop it from memory to allow the new app to use it.

Of course, the reason a consumer-oriented desktop OS like macOS or Windows is bulkier than such as linux is the sheer quantity of 'user experience' features. If you really want an OS to be bare-bones, then you can sacrifice the 'ease' of use for a skinny stripped down version of nix that will do just as much… but won't help you out as a  newbie. It will make you research every function, then type it in, in Terminal. Many modern nixes don't go all the way down to this, they also have some 'user comfort' added.

Comment: The OS consists of a lot more than _wired_ memory. macOS, like all modern operating systems, has lots and lots of userspace components.

Comment: @DanielB -I'm simplifying, to suit the question.  I don't have the energy [or chops] to explain to someone who hasn't yet grokked the broad strokes of modern RAM usage. Keep the detail for detailed enquiries. OP is also looking at default 'My Processes', not All.

Comment: @DanielB Modern operating systems, such as Linux on a Raspberry Pi, will operate comfortably with less than 1GB RAM. The GUI is not part of the OS and should not be considered part of the *wired* memory (whatever that is).

Answer (score 0):

Since Vista Business (Pro) (Windows) 64-bit 15years ago, 64-bit systems (All Windows, and as far as I know, Mac) take a basic 4 GB (+-) to run.

The address space for a 32-bit workstation only allowed 3 GB (+-) and 64-bit allows a much larger address space for bigger applications. 4 GB has always worked decently (for me) since that time.

Memory is inexpensive, so just outfit your machine with 8 GB of memory (or more) and that will definitely alleviate your issue.

Since much runs in the basic 4 GB space, there does not seem to a basic drive to reduce the memory requirement.

Comment: Vista Home Premium would easily run with 2 GB of RAM. Home Basic edition was recommended for 1 GB IIRC. RAM requirements were steadily increasing since ever, I guess, because you can't do more stuff without using more memory.

Comment: I have had 4+ GB of memory since 2008 and most  stuff works in that space.  I did not see a reason to try to use less memory.

Comment: You can't add RAM to a Mac after purchase. OP already has 8GB, which is pretty basic in this day & age. I wouldn't buy anything with less than 16GB these days.

Comment: @gronostaj - Microsoft's official stance was that Vista could run on a system with only 1 GB but in reality the performance of Vista on a system with 1 GB, was so horrible that Vista is now known as one of the worst operating systems that exists. Despite the fact I used it for nearly 5 years without a single complaint.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not completely true. Apple [does](https://support.apple.com/guide/system-information/upgrade-memory-syspa6de5c9d/mac) let you upgrade RAM on some/most systems.

Comment: @doneal24 - "some/most" ...not really. Mac Pro & older iMac/mini in the main. Laptops have been soldered [BGA] or SOC RAM since about 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Memory usage in a modern OS is highly optimized. That is the OS tries to make the most efficient use of available memory. But efficient use of memory does not mean using less.

The old idea of memory use was that memory was a precious resource that should be used as sparingly as possible. That was necessary in old operating systems running on hardware with limited resources. That was the case even on mainframes through the 1950's.

But in the late 1950's the idea of a virtual memory OS was introduced. Note that virtual memory does not mean pagefile or swapfile. There is much more to it than that. This idea was further developed during the 1960's and by the end of the decade it was generally regarded as superior to other memory management systems. That remains true in 2022. This is for general purpose operating systems, not those for specialized needs.

Small computer systems, the kind that would be used by a home or small business, generally did not have the hardware resources needed for a modern virtual memory OS until the 1990's. By the dawn of the 21st century Windows, Linux, and the Mac all had a form of a virtual memory OS. This includes smartphones as well.

In such a system memory is recognized as the fastest storage medium and thus should be used to the fullest possible extent. Free memory is the ultimate in wasted memory memory, something that should be avoided if at all possible. The ideal would be zero free memory at all times, but we aren't there yet.

Memory usage in a modern OS is highly dynamic. The OS memory manager controls how much memory a process can have and how long it can keep it. The goal is always to optimize overall system performance, not to minimize memory usage. When there is no memory pressure processes are allowed pretty much whatever memory they want with few restrictions. This is best for performance.

But when memory pressure increases the OS makes some adjustments. The memory usage of processes is trimmed back to meet the increased demand. A modern OS also has several forms of cache whose size and contents are adjusted according to need and memory availability. All of this is done totally transparent to applications. The memory usage of an application on the same computer doing the same thing can vary by a factor of 10 or more depending on memory pressure. And all completely normal.

The computer in the screenshot appears to be operating normally as was designed. Unfortunately the principles used are not well understood by most computer users and that often leads to confusion.